# Remove first character after casting

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting, trim

I have the following select statement to view encrypted data.

```
SELECT 
 cast(cast([ID] as varbinary (max)) as varchar (max)) as ID
,cast(cast([Filter] as varbinary (max)) as varchar (max)) as Filter
,cast(cast([English] as varbinary (max)) as varchar (max)) as Description
FROM [Alpha].[dbo].[LangDescription]
```

I'd like to remove the leading character from the ID field.  Any idea how I can incorporate the two?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax looks like [t-sql](/questions/tagged/t-sql), so I would suggest using [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

```
SELECT 
 STUFF(cast(cast([ID] as varbinary (max)) as varchar (max)), 1, 1, '') as ID
,cast(cast([Filter] as varbinary (max)) as varchar (max)) as Filter
,cast(cast([English] as varbinary (max)) as varchar (max)) as Description
FROM [Alpha].[dbo].[LangDescription]
```

Comment: Please avoid writing code in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: The response by Zohar was very helpful.. Thank you